# String concatenation in SQLite for an iphone app

Tags: ios, html, sqlite, cordova, concatenation

Basically im trying to join two tables in order to only access certain results, however the query returns that there are no rows in the table, which i know is false?

can anyone suggest a better way to join the tables/concatenate the strings?

here is the current code:

```
function queryDBcolours(tx) {
    var carid = document.finalfrm.CarID.value;
    var myquery = 'SELECT DC.CarImg ,C.ColourImg,C.Colour, C.ColourID FROM CarColours DC,Colours C WHERE DC.ColourID = C.ColourID AND C.Type =\"Car\" AND DC.CarID = '+varcarid;
    tx.executeSql(myquery, [], querySuccesscolours, errorCB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you log out your sql statement and try to execute it in sqlite manually, do it work?  Seems like you need a 'join' in there.

Comment: is this what you are looking for?select DC.CarImg ,C.ColourImg,C.Colour, C.ColourID 
from CarColours DC
inner join Colours C
on DC.ColourID = C.ColourID
where C.Type =\"Car\" AND DC.CarID = XXXXX

Comment: every time I try to join tables, your way or mine, it always returns 0 rows, even though both tables when queried individually return x number of rows :/

Comment: something is amiss somewhere.  Try building a small select statement in sqlite manager/express and then adding more to it once it returns rows, something like select * from carcolours inner join colours on carcolours.colourid = colours.coloursid where carcolours.colourid = some valid colourid.